# SQL Convert mixed exchange rates to local currency

Tags: sql, function, user-defined-functions

I have expenses recorded with Mixed Exchange Rates. `dbo.fn_KurBul (@DATE, @EXCHANGERATE, 1)`

@DATE : Current Date
@EXCHANGERATE: 0-TURKISHLIRA, 1-DOLLAR, 2-EURO'"
With that function.
I can convert it to the current exchange rate with the function, but since exchange rates are complicated, how can I apply this per line?

```
SELECT 
    T.UserTableID,
    SERVICEID,
    F.COMPANYNAME,
    TEXT1,
    CONVERT(INT,Periot),
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    T.YEAR,
    DATEDIFF( day,GETDATE(),EndDate ),
    CONVERT( nvarchar, CONVERT(INT,(MONTHPRICE)) ) + ExchangeRate,
    CONVERT(nvarchar,YEARPRICE) + ExchangeRate
FROM
    TABLE1 AS T WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 F WITH(NOLOCK) ON
        F.COMPANYNAME = T.COMPANYNAME
```

```
SELECT 
    T.UserTableID,
    SERVICEID,
    F.COMPANYNAME,
    TEXT1,
    CONVERT(INT,Periot),
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    T.YEAR,
    DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),EndDate),
    CONVERT(nvarchar,CONVERT (INT,(MONTHPRICE))) + ExchangeRate,
    CONVERT(nvarchar,YEARPRICE) + ExchangeRate
FROM
    TABLE1 AS T WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 F WITH(NOLOCK) ON
        F.COMPANYNAME = T.COMPANYNAME
```

this is my sql query.
I have tried declaring

```
DECLARE @dolarprice int

SELECT
    @dolarprice = MONTHPRICE * dbo.fn_getexchangerate( GETDATE(), 2, 1 )  
FROM
    TABLE
WHERE
    EXCHANGERATE = '$'
ORDER BY
    MONTH
```

but that gave me single value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CQlk.png)

this is how my table looks like.
AYLIKGIDER = MONTHPRICE
YILLIKGIDER= YEARPRICE

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. The above code is product specific.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: You need to add meaningful names to your columns - currently at least half of them are unnamed... and schema-qualify your object references. And remove the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hints, and add length parameters to `nvarchar` (otherwise it's the same as `nvarchar(1)` which is pointless) and use UTC instead of `GETDATE()`.

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` <-- This is a very, very, bad, bad idea. There is no legitimate reason for doing this.